# Error in export sql server database

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have SQL server and SQL management studio 2012. After i create tables and when i export the data base to the server "online" every "primary and auto incremental" field become as a normal field. so when i try to add row to database i have the following error
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'taskID', table 'lawyersDB.dbo.tasks'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

To solve this problem i have to manage the database "online" and go to each table and set again the fields primary and auto incremental. Since i have many tables, this process takes lot of time.
So Any idea to solve this problem!?

Note: my hosting is on Arvix company server

Comment: Could you walk me through the `export the data base to the server "online"` part? I don't believe I'm familiar with that features in SSMS

Answer (score 0):

This is SQL Management Studio, not your account.

Try this:

You need to set this, or else if you have a non-nullable column, with no default error, if you provide no value it will error.

To set up auto-increment in SQL Server Management Studio:

Open your table in Design
Select your column and go to Column Properties
Under Indentity Specification, set (Is Identity)=Yes and Indentity Increment=1